# How to indicate possession by e.g. passers-by, mothers-in-law

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives

I'm quite fond of internal pluralisation, such as passers-by, mothers-in-law, or even [Chambers of Commerce](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4064/chambers-of-commerce).

However, I've recently realised that I've no idea how to indicate possession in such a case.

Neither "Mothers-in-law's" nor "mothers'-in-law" seem right.

Is there a corrct way of doing this, or should it just be avoided?

Comment: My favourite internal pluralisations: Advocates General and Procurators Fiscal.

Comment: ...and Directors General and Secretaries General.

Comment: I think I've found a paper on this! But I can't read it. Oh well. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10214215

Comment: What is that paper doing on PubMed anyway? Are there any health issues associated with building possessives?

Comment: @RegDwight: The paper is from "Nurse Author Ed", or the "[Nurse, Author & Editor Newsletter](http://www.nurseauthoreditor.com/)".

Comment: `...and Directors General and Secretaries General.`  Gah.  I call them General Directors and General Secretaries.  Noun-adjective is a nasty throwback from French influence over English.  Oh, and it's Marshall Courts, too.  ;-)

Comment: FWIW, this speed bump doesn't exist in constructed languages, at least, not in Esperanto. In Esperanto, there is no "internal pluralization" in the first place. So, for example, passer-by is "preterpasanto", and passers-by is "preterpasantoj".

Answer (score 11):

"Mothers-in-law's" is a correct form.  I am quoting the rule used in American grammar:

> Also add an apostrophe followed by an s to the end of a singular compound noun that ends in any letter except s. For example:
>
> 1. Queen of England's carriage
> 2. King of Spain's castle
> 3. Prime Minister of Canada's question
> 4. mother-in-law's recipe

Comment: "Mother-in-law's" is clearly correct, but "mothers-in-law's" still seems wrong.

Comment: I agree with your conclusion that “mothers-in-law’s” is the correct form.  However, the rule which you quoted does not apply here because it explicitly states that it is about _singular_ compound nouns.

Comment: "This is especially useful in pluralized compound structures: the daughters-in-law's car sounds quite strange, but it's correct. We're better off with the car of the daughters-in-law." http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/possessives.htm

Answer (score 7):

I suggest avoiding it. No matter how you put it, half of your audience will think you got it wrong and be distracted.

Try "the recipes of the mothers-in-law."

Comment: I agree that such possessives are usually best avoided: even though "the Queen of England's carriage" is grammatically correct, it is a bit ugly. Unless it is a usage hallowed by time or convention, I'd rephrase it as "the carriage of the Queen/King/Monarch of England (whichever is applicable)".