# Plural of passerby

Tags: grammar, orthography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Words that are pluralized in the middle?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8450/words-that-are-pluralized-in-the-middle)

Why is the plural of "passerby" "passers-by" and not "passerbies"?

Comment: Related: [Words that are pluralized in the middle?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8450/)

Comment: Yes, this question seems like a duplicate of that one.  (Or at least, this is subsumed by the other.)  Also related, though not quite the same: [possessives of such words](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4626/how-to-indicate-possession-by-e-g-passers-by-mothers-in-law).

Comment: I'm not certain that this question is a duplicate of the other one. This asks why such words are pluralized in this way, and the other question just asks for more such examples.

Answer (score 0):

I have no authorative source, but my common sense explanation is that the word is derived from the verb phrase `to pass by something`. As the noun-constructing suffix got attached to the verb part `pass`, making it `passer`, it is logical to chain the plural suffix -s after the first suffix. The `by` part is more of an additional particle for the word, I think it is even acceptable to write `passers-by` with a dash.

A weak point in this explanation is that other nouns derived from compound verbs don't build a plural in the middle (compare `turnout`, `makeover`). But those don't use a suffix to create the noun, so no noun-chaining can occur.

Comment: I believe the middle *s* only pops up in words whose first part cannot be a verb, only a noun: in "turnout" and "makeover", it is conceivable that they originated in phrases. You could say "the war will turn out fine": I cannot think of any usage of the noun "turn" that could result in a "turnout". In words like "makeover" and "let-down", it is even clearer that they come from verbal parts. If it existed, the imaginary word **passby* would come from the verb "to pass", not the noun, so **passbys*; in *passer-*, as you say, the suffix clearly makes it a noun.