# How to denote possession with "Bureau of Statistics"

Tags: possessives, apostrophe, saxon-genitive

When denoting possession with Bureau of Statistics, does one use "Bureau's of Statistics" or "Bureau of Statistics'"?

E.g.

> - according to the Bureau's of Statistics Consumer Price Index
> - according to the Bureau of Statistics' Consumer Price Index

Comment: Perhaps surprisingly, [How to indicate possession by e.g. passers-by, mothers-in-law](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4626/how-to-indicate-possession-by-e-g-passers-by-mothers-in-law) does cover this.

Comment: I believe that answer leaves it ambiguous in this particular case, as the accepted answer is: "Also add an apostrophe followed by an s to the end of a singular compound noun that ends in any letter except s"
Does this simply imply in the alternate case, to add an apostrophe after the s?

Comment: Yes. The final word in the compound noun gets pluralised and "possessivised" in the normal way.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/79083/2085).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second form:

> according to the Bureau of Statistics' Consumer Price Index