# Plural of "Runner-Up"

Tags: grammatical-number

Why is it "runners-up", as opposed to the naïve "runner-ups"?

Is there a rule to remember for these situations?

Comment: Related: [Chambers of Commerce?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4064/)

Comment: *Chambers of Commerce* is well established. The likes of *runner-up* are not quite the same.

Comment: The OP is asking "why", not which form is correct, so I don't think the question should be closed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The hyphenate *runner-up* contains a noun and an adverb/preposition. Only nouns can be pluralized. Since it is still hyphenated, the parts maintain their grammatical value.

Comment: Thanks. I guess, 10 years into the future, when "runner-up" has been molten into "runnerup", its plural would change. ;)

Comment: Now I'm curious: Why is it *"pat-downs"*, not *"pats-down"*?

Comment: @Tomalak:  I think in that case SingLow's answer doesn't quite apply.  I think the components are a verb and a preposition, and only together do they become a noun, and thus you pluralize the whole thing.  Same goes for sit-ups and push-ups.

Comment: @Tomalak seems to be one of many cases in the English language where there is a rule, and way too many exceptions for the rule.