# Plural of "daughter in law"

Tags: grammatical-number, kinship-terms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Words that are pluralized in the middle?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8450/words-that-are-pluralized-in-the-middle)

I was asked to write the plural of *daughter in law* in an aptitude exam. I wrote it as *daughters in law*. Please tell me the right answer.

Comment: I know from my military experience that the plural of 'Sergeant Major" is "Sergeants Major", so I am inclined to believe you got it right.

Comment: Related: [Plural of “Runner-Up”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7015/plural-of-runner-up), [Chambers of Commerce?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4064/chambers-of-commerce)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are right.
 When pluralizing words like "-in-law" or "-in-chief", The noun is pluralized, not the modifiers following. Hence:

> "Fathers-in-law" not "Father-in-laws"

and

> "Commanders-in-chief" not "Commander-in-chiefs"

Answer (score 2):

A handy link is available at http://www.ehow.com/how_5620678_spell-plural-fatherinlaw-similar-words.html.

> 1. Always connect the parts of these family nouns with hyphens (-) in both the singular and plural. Thus we write "father-in-law," "sister-in-law" or "brother-in-law." It is not considered correct to write them without hyphens.
> 2. Form the plural by adding "s" to the noun, and not to "law." Thus we can write, two "mothers-in-law" and three "sisters-in-law." These are the correct forms even though native speakers may not use them.