# Plural form of "Son-in-law"

Tags: grammatical-number, kinship-terms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Words that are pluralized in the middle?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8450/words-that-are-pluralized-in-the-middle)

I've heard it pronounced both ways:

> Sons-in-law

and

> Son-in-laws

While one may be more technically correct than the other, are they both equally acceptable based on popular usage?

Comment: See also [Plural of "daughter in law"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29464/plural-of-daughter-in-law), which has been closed as duplicate of the first question I reported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Sons-in-law" is proper. Think of the hyphenated suffix "-in-law" as an adjective, which was its original purpose. It would be equivalent to "partner**s** in crime".

Comment: Note that the -possessive- does follow the somewhat illogical 'add the 's' to the very end", e.g. "son-in-law's".